# laravel sail - Can't understand why log is keep piling even when no requests are made

Tags: php, logging, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I'm working with laravel 8, on `sail` - on `WSL2`,
and for some reason, the file: `/project/storage/logs/laravel.log` is being filled again and again by the error (attached).

Every second... every day i have to delete the files when it gets to be 20GB size..

The strange thing is that there are no requests made to the server. the browsers are closed!
Moreover - when I do access the server - it works without any errors.

```
[2023-04-07 01:31:56] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `categories`) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `categories`) at /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:759)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(898): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback()
#1 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(878): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection()
#2 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(722): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->handleQueryException()
#3 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(421): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run()
#4 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2630): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select()
#5 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2618): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->runSelect()
#6 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3154): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2619): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->onceWithColumns()
#8 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(698): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->get()
#9 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(682): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->getModels()
#10 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(568): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->get()
#11 /var/www/project/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php(32): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::all()
#12 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider->boot()
#13 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#14 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#15 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#16 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#17 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(930): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#18 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(911): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootProvider()
#19 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->Illuminate\\Foundation\\{closure}()
#20 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(912): array_walk()
#21 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->boot()
#22 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(239): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\BootProviders->bootstrap()
#23 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith()
#24 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#25 Command line code(1): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#26 {main}
```

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not your mySQL server is running?

Comment: @Daedalus It is. when i open my browser the app is working without problems. i also can access it with workbench

Comment: Check this line in your error log: `var/www/project/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php(32)`, first copy/paste that part in your original question. Then check for your exact error message, it's an easy fix

Comment: @UnderDog Two issues: 1) this line works. i have the data. 2) the log keep growing even when no (known) requests are made to the server..

Comment: @yossi Perhaps I am wrong, but the last line in your error log makes me think this code is being called via CLI.  Do you have a cron job running?

Comment: @yossi Was I right or wrong?

Comment: @Daedalus
Couldn't find out.. the docker container has no crontab and i don't want to mess with the container now. But I think that there are no default cronjobs on laravel sail..